# clone() not working internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, clone

I have this code:

```
openPopup.hide();

var substr = popupId.split('-');                        
var clone = $("#popup"+substr[1]).clone(true);

$("#popup"+substr[1]).remove();
$(openPopup).html(clone);
$.dimScreenStop();
```

It works well in IE 7, IE 9, Chrome, Firefox.

I have tracked the problem down to the line "*var clone = $("#popup"+substr[1]).clone(true);*". This by adding "*alert("Test");*" between all the lines and after that line (in IE8) it doesn't output the alert.

The strange thing is that I get error in the jquery min-file (just in IE8 no other browser, or browser version):

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'nodeType': object is null or undefined 
jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1, line 2 character 4426**

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Im using version 1.7.1, will update and try the last one.

Comment: Now it is the latest version 1.8.2, doesn't change anything, Im afraid.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the javascript DOM API cloneNode() method instead of jQuery's clone().
More informations on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

Example :

```
var clone = $("#node").get(0).cloneNode(true);
var $clone = $(clone); // JQUERY object

$('#copy').empty().html($clone.html());​
```

===> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NdXh8/1/)

Comment: Thanks for answer! The thing is that this "script" is a popup wiith a youtube video in it, which displays when you click a link. I want be able to click the link, get the popup and then close it multiple times. So if Im right, the code above wont work the second time clicking the link?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but cloneNode is an alternative for clone in IE.

Answer (score 2):

`.clone()` gives you a **jQuery extended element** and **not HTML text**. Even though `.html()` is accommodating enough to accept jQuery objects, this is not what it was originally intended for.

As a solution, try using `$(openPopup).empty().append(clone);` instead of `$(openPopup).html(clone);`

Comment: Thanks for answer! Im afraid that it doesn't help. The problem is on the line "var clone = $("#popup"+substr[1]).clone(true);" in IE8, because It doesn't execute anything below that line. So editing the line .html(clone); want affect.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. Try alerting the value of `substr[1]` before cloning. `alert(substr[1])` - That might give you some hints.

Comment: It works fine, alerting the id in the end of the div-id name.